# Sorting different objects by a common value

Tags: java, sorting, object

I have many different weapon classes and enemy/player classes. They all have a common y variable that they update.. How can I sort them according to that y value? They will all (hopefully) be in an array list. Reading somewhere I saw that you can add a parameter to `Collections.sort()` but I couldn't figure out how to do it with many classes.

Also, is there a java equivalent to dynamic lists in c#?

Comment: Have your classes implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Seriously? Haven't you been spoon-fed enough by Meesh already? Google it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your enemy/player classes have a single parent (class or interface), which it sounds like they do if you are making a List of them, you can use the [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and put some sort of `getY` method in the parent class/interface that your `Comparator` can make use of.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't all have a similar class, they were copied to form each other. I wrote that part before I knew about that.

Comment: The quickest fix sounds like you should make an interface and have them all implement it.  Add getY in the interface and then all of the classes will have to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comparator which uses the value of `y` as sorting value. If you don't want to expose a public method returning the value of `y` you can write a **package-private** Comparator class and use the method `Collections.sort(list, MyComparator)`.

e.g.:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

   @Override public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
       return Float.compare(p1.y, p2.y);
   }
}
```